# Trying to find if the element of an int array is equal to a number entered in C

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to use a for loop to iterate over the elements of an integer array and find out if a particular element in that array is equal to some other integer.

Here's what I've got, and it doesn't seem to work:

```
int squaresArray[1000];
int numberOfSquares = 1000;
int i = 0;

for (i; i<=numberOfSquares; i++)
{
    squaresArray[i] = i*i;
    if (number == squaresArray[i]){
        printf("%d is a perfect square\n", number);}
        break;
}
```

According to what I know about for loops this should work, but it prints nothing even when the number should be equal to some element of the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're breaking on the first iteration due to misplaced brackets (i.e. `break` is not in the scope of the `if`-statement). Change it to:

```
if (number == squaresArray[i]) {
        printf("%d is a perfect square\n", number);  // no closing bracket here
        break;
} // <--
```

Also, your loop condition should probably be `i < numberOfSquares`. After all, `numberOfSquares` (`1000`) is an out of bounds index for an array of length 1000. Moreover, you don't need a loop initialization statement if you've already declared/initialized `i` in the loop's enclosing scope. Hence, we're left with

```
int i = 0;

for (; i < numberOfSquares; i++)
```

If you're using C99 and above, you can limit the scope of `i` to only the loop, which should be preferred:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSquares; i++)
```

Comment: Thanks for that, it fixed it. I think it was simply to do with the misplaced bracket.

Comment: Actuall, "i < numberOfSquares" is equally important (can you say "potential access violation?") ;)

Comment: Ah yes, I fixed that as well, but now I have other issues with it.:)